# Why does this CustomJShover code not work?

Tags: time, bokeh, number-formatting

The goal is to get the time for hovertool box.

I have formatted the y axis in bokeg with NumeralTickFormatter
The given number was formatted to time, hours:minutes

I want that in the Hovertool, too.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=acts,
    y=semit,    
))
```

```
p.add_tools(HoverTool(
    tooltips=[

             ("time", "$y{00:00:00}")
    ],
    formatters={
        "$y" : 'numeral',   
                            
    },
    # display a tooltip whenever the cursor is vertically in line with a glyph
    mode='vline'
)
)
```

I have used this on y axis and works well:

```
p.yaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format= '00:00:00')
```

Comment: You want `@y` not `$y`.

Comment: I tried but not working.

and tried CustomJShover

tim_custom = CustomJSHover(code="""

const format_times = (time) => {
    var hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((time % 3600) / 60);
    var seconds = time % 60;
    return `${hours.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
}
return `Time: ${format_times(cb_data.time)}`;
""")

p.add_tools(HoverTool(
    tooltips=[( 'Time','@time{custom}' )],

    formatters={'@time':tim_custom}
))

Comment: I solved it.

I needed to change the ColumnDataSource a bit.

It is okay now. 

You were correct with the use of this charaters $ @ 

Thanks!!